# R: Cannot show rowname when extract only one row

Tags: r

Suppose I have `x` like this

```
              [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]
rs1952251 12.05886 23.72529 30.92366 37.53577 43.64377 46.75088 48.93301
rs3009943 11.90153 22.70790 30.29965 32.53084 34.70415 36.29477 37.77274
```

I would like to extract first row and make that as a 1 by 7 matrix. I use `x[1,]`. But I got

```
> x[1,]
[1] 12.05886 23.72529 30.92366 37.53577 43.64377 46.75088 48.93301
```

It is a vector and it does not have rownames.
I would like to get something as following:

```
              [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]
rs1952251 12.05886 23.72529 30.92366 37.53577 43.64377 46.75088 48.93301
```

Comment: Can't find a dup here but - http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-keep-row-name-if-there-is-only-one-row-selected-from-a-data-frame-td895594.html

Comment: @alistaire - I think that's close enough - swtiching row to column is essentially identical.

Answer (score 2):

You could try converting to a data frame before you take the subset:

```
data.frame(x)[1,]
```

Comment: No need to convert, just specify `x[1,,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: @thelatemail.Thanks